# cURL stristr errors

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to figure out why this won't work for me. I'm a complete noob when it comes to cURL, today is my first day using it. I followed a tutorial for this but obviously failed.

It should check the page and if it sees "Skill Stats" on there, then return "Success", and return "Failure" if it spots "Member Rankings".

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore/compare.ws?user1=Mercon185");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);


if (stristr($output,"Skill Stats")) {
    echo 'Success';
}
if (stristr($output,"Member Rankings")) {
    echo 'Failure';
}

curl_close($ch);
?>
```

`

Comment: So what do you get back? Did you `echo $output;` to see what it returned? Did you check `curl_error($ch)` for errors?

Comment: first check if `$output` has any data

Comment: var_dump and echo $output; both return nothing. It's a blank white page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable follow redirects. As I see currently, your URL redirects to http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore/overall.ws?errorcode=1. Without follow redirects enabled, it only fetches the first page, which indeed is empty.

The final landing page though, contains the data you want, so if you add this line to your cURL options, it should work:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```